# Something is wrong with extrusion in blender 2.8

Tags: extrude

Whenever I press e to extrude, no new geometry is generated, instead the surrounding geometry is warped towards my cursor. This is different from what the tutorial I'm following shows, and I looked around and I see that extrusion should work differently.
Currently, when i try to extrude an edge by pressing 'e', it ends up like so:
[image]

As you can imagine, I need help.

Comment: you must have changed the shortcut by accident, maybe try to extrude by the horizontal menu bar > edge > extrude edge

Comment: I tried that, it's the same result.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem as this user for the last 2 beta releases. The geometry is not being "created", the entire object is moving with the extruded face/vertex. You have to right-click to "cancel" after every extrusion with 'e'  or duplication with shift-d and alt-d. Then you can move the extruded face/vertex (or duplicated object) away from the original geometry with the 'g' key. Looks like at least now the entire object isn't moving, just the components being extruded, but this is still a **huge pain in the @$$**

Comment: Oh dear, that really doesn't seem good at all. But it's something, at least. Now I can progress in my tutorial. Here's hoping the method doesn't have any negative side effects. Thanks.